# Text overlay in heatmap

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Is it possible to overlay text in selectable heatmap

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/selection_heatmap

If I plot a heatmap of actual vs predicted for binary in the selectable heatmap, can I overlay text as True Positives, FP, TN, FN with corresponding values
and turn off legend

Here full code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"actual": "Good", "predicted": "Bad", "count": 6386},
      {"actual": "Bad", "predicted": "Good", "count": 1261},
      {"actual": "Bad", "predicted": "Bad", "count": 6386},
      {"actual": "Good", "predicted": "Good", "count": 24030}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "rect", "strokeWidth": 2},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "actual",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "predicted",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "fill": {
      "field": "count",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
  "config": {
    "scale": {
      "bandPaddingInner": 0,
      "bandPaddingOuter": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Output like
[image]

Is it possible to extract values from index and feed to count values

```
    "url" : {
        "%context%": true,
        "index": "index",
        "body": {
          "size":1000,
          "_source": ["modelMetrics"],
        }
      }  
    "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
  },
```

where index has

```
        "_source" : {
          "modelMetrics" : {
            "TN" : 110868,
            "FP" : 6386,
            "FN" : 1261,
            "TP" : 24030,
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [Layered chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/layer.html) construct. For example ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAEyUALJQBWENgDsQAGhAATJJhSpQxJIIZwIaANqgkUTA31oQAcTZs1KkDgBOcNTUufbAISRnVUEkJjhBWwAxAAUXKDYGBUw0ADYAZgAOFIBfZXNLawj0AKDXDy8fZ3QHJxcQsKKQSIA5OISktABGMRTO3PyrG2LAl3dPb0xfYdL68NsAFVbVeMTk1HSs-pALQcaa0rGKyar7RxnQufR52OX2tbFJAAY0x+yAXVyQOAV4rwUyNCgACegJAADMaOETjtCi5MECcHBbAo2AgaAobJ8AB6giFQ2yHCa+VTwxHI1HozGfEJAuBuUygZBuADWoNJSPQHksLggmDcbGZcAA6jQ1PQ0GJPt9fuiATpwTRBEVQHjBCcVh0SQiOSAAI7WJJ0TQ0Uh1cjfKoKBhK7K2vIgJms+Xs2yTLHJVRqEGofgAVilPycsrZcHduMhatsswiWrJ6BRaIxEU+8UEbHp8viCi8mHYSmdRjW6k0DAQlA1mAABAAeSudR4Nx4uPQGHVMEJQVmfFuGWwAdxgIhAtq2jrZ2tdoY96m9-tU0qD-xDYflqvVdzhE-jFKTw9uaYzoCzObzId5tg0VjLFZrdcbTdUPbbHa7j-0vfQA6HI7eqj7ovFVB60eVR4BoMgsC6BtsiAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"actual": "Good", "predicted": "Bad", "label": "FP", "count": 6386},
      {"actual": "Bad", "predicted": "Good", "label": "FN", "count": 1261},
      {"actual": "Bad", "predicted": "Bad", "label": "TN", "count": 6386},
      {"actual": "Good", "predicted": "Good", "label": "TP", "count": 24030}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "actual", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "predicted", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "fill": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative", "legend": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.count < 10000", "value": "black"},
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": 5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "count", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.count < 10000", "value": "black"},
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to extract values from index and feed only to count values for this plot, edited the last section of post. Thanks

Comment: I figured that out, Thanks